# Android Studio 0.8 screen record with microphone?

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-recording

I need to take a screen record of my Nexus 4 in Android 4.4.4. 
Everything works fine but my video have no sound and I need it for explaining stuff about the app meanwhile I'm recording it.

There's a way to save the sound of my microphone ( whatever if it from my computer microphone or my mobile) and the video?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in Windows or MAC?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the native screen recording introduced in KitKat does not support recording audio. You would need to record audio using another program (either desktop or possibly using another app on the phone) during your screen recording.

Once you have the exported video, you would need to edit it and add your recorded audio track. Since you stated you are on Windows, a tool such as Windows Movie Maker should be able to do the job quite easily.

Another potential option if your device is rooted, you could give an application such as [Rec](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spectrl.rec) a shot, it supports screen recording with audio recorded from the microphone.